# Where can I access public sonic well-log data?

Tags: geology, geophysics, seismology

I'm doing some research and I'm in need of some well-log data from a sonic tool. I'm specifically looking for a multi-receiver tool with 6 or more receivers if possible.

I've been able to find a lot of 2D/3D seismic data such as SEG data pool but well-log data seems in very short supply.

Answer (score 2):

Equinor released a complete data set from the Volve field 2008-2016. From their website, it appears that the data is intended for the researchers. It has data from the sonic tool as well.

Here is the link [Volve field data set](https://www.equinor.com/energy/volve-data-sharing)

Answer (score 1):

For **USA** data, I recommend searching state-by-state (preferably ones that are well-developed [Alaska, Texas, Louisiana, New Mexico, Pennsylvania, etc.]) and specifically targeting data sources that are the state-level commissions for all past/current/future leases. For example, the Texas Rail Road Commission (or RRC) has a lot of info that *may* provide the type of well-log data you seek. [See here](https://www.rrc.texas.gov/oil-and-gas/research-and-statistics/obtaining-commission-records/oil-gas-well-records-gis-well-logs/).

For some other **data from elsewhere**, check [this huge data set](https://terranubis.com/datainfo/F3-Demo-2020) out from dGB (and OpendTect) from the North Sea.